# Is there a way to parse positional files in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, parsing

I have an input file consisting of records in positional format (ex. Column `First Name` is in positions 1 to 10)

Like so:
`John      Doe       john@example.com`

This is obviously oversimplified. I really have over 25 columns, so using `Mid` is possible but overly complicated. I guess I could write a class that would parse it, but I would like to make sure these isn't a better way before I waste time on it.

Comment: What's the delimiter? Is it Tab or always n number of spaces? You could try CSV Helper to break it out. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Custom-Configurations

Comment: @TyCobb: there is no delimiter, thats why its so hard. Otherwise it would be a simple `String.Parse()`. But it is in positional format. So, Columns always have a fixed size. All columns have a fixed number of positions.

Comment: That's actually not that bad then. More monotonous than anything. Give me a few. I'll write a small example of what I did a few years ago for this.

Comment: @TyCobb: Give me a couple minutes I'll work out a sample File and Pastebin it. I just need to know HOW to do it so I can add more columns later if I need to and to actually learn something. :)

Comment: I don't need a sample file. Just giving you an example based on what you pasted  =P   It should suit your needs based on your description.

Comment: @TyCobb: Great! Post it when you done, please! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser class can parse fixed width formats. Basic usage is to create an instance of the class, set a property to indicate the format is fixed-width, call a method to specify the widths of each column, then start a loop to read the data one record at a time. Here's [an example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash.aspx). In this example, the file has 4 columns of width 5, width 10, and width 11, with the last being of unlimited length (the -1).

```
Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\TestFolder\test.log")
  Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
  Reader.SetFieldWidths(5, 10, 11, -1)

  Dim currentRow As String()
  While Not Reader.EndOfData
    Try
      currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
      Dim currentField As String 
      For Each currentField In currentRow
        MsgBox(currentField)
      Next 
    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
      MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")
    End Try
  End While 
End Using
```

Comment: Can a string be used as an input?

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @TyCobb: Oh, right. I didn't have time to begin reading the docs for the class.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan's answer is much more appropriate (had no idea that class existed) for what you need.

However, since I already wrote the C# version of this I figure I will keep this posted here as it may come in handy for others in the future

---

Basically, create some delegates to handle the actual actions of each column. Then just loop through lines and `Substring` for each section. As pointed out in the comments, `Substring` is not very optimal, however, it is very easy to take this and change up how the columns are actually read.

**VB.NET Version**

```
Public Class Person

    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Email As String

End Class

Public Class ColumnHandler

    Public Property Process As Action(Of Person, String)

    Public Property Length As Integer

    Public Sub New(processAction As Action(Of Person, String), columnLength As Integer)
        Process = processAction
        Length = columnLength
    End Sub

End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim columnHandlers() As ColumnHandler =
            {
                New ColumnHandler(Sub(p, s) p.FirstName = s, 10),
                New ColumnHandler(Sub(p, s) p.LastName = s, 10),
                New ColumnHandler(Sub(p, s) p.Email = s, 16)
            }

        Dim fileLines() As String =
            {
                "John      Doe       john@example.com",
                "Ty        Cobb      anon@example.com"
            }

        Dim people As New List(Of Person)

        For Each line As String In fileLines

            Dim currentPosition As Integer = 0
            Dim person As New Person()

            For Each columnHandler As ColumnHandler In columnHandlers
                columnHandler.Process.Invoke(person, line.Substring(currentPosition, columnHandler.Length).Trim())
                currentPosition += columnHandler.Length
            Next

            people.Add(person)

        Next

        Console.WriteLine(people.Count.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine(people(1).LastName)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

**C# Version** (since I apparently don't know how to read question tags or titles)

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var columnHandlers = new[]
    {
        new {Process = new Action<Person, string>((p, s) => p.FirstName = s), Length = 10},
        new {Process = new Action<Person, string>((p, s) => p.LastName = s), Length = 10},
        new {Process = new Action<Person, string>((p, s) => p.Email = s), Length = 16},
    };

    //Replace this with a stream or however you were going to get/read the lines
    var fileLines = new[]
    {
        "John      Doe       john@example.com",
        "Ty        Cobb      anon@example.com",
    };

    var people = new List<Person>();

    foreach (var line in fileLines)
    {
        var currentPosition = 0;
        var person = new Person();
        foreach (var columnHandler in columnHandlers)
        {
            columnHandler.Process(person, line.Substring(currentPosition, columnHandler.Length).Trim());
            currentPosition += columnHandler.Length;
        }

        people.Add(person);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(people.Count.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(people[1].LastName);
}
```

Comment: Sure. I'll check out Ryan's answer for now.

Comment: Ok, TyCobb, I also think it's a bit cleaner.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN It should be the answer you really want to use. I had no clue VB had a class for that.

Comment: Your answer also seems very interesting and can be useful in some cases.

Comment: <sbs> btw using substring on large strings will leak on the LOH, use indexed access to the string

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN Heh, like I said in my comment to your question -- just an example. Can be easily changed to go character by character. I just really like having the delegates do the actual work against the column data.